# .ply polygonal mesh to 2D depth map

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, mesh

I am trying to convert a polygonal mesh in `.ply` format into a 2-D depth map, to be saved in a standard array or image format.

Ideally I'd like to use python, but would be open something else if it's simpler.  I'm looking for something to use in a pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/) wich is open source and can do exactly what you want.

Follow this steps:

- Download Meshlab from the link above.
- Import your .ply mesh:

[image: import mesh]

- Go to Render-> Shaders -> depthmap.gdp:

[image: depthmap]

- Change `zmin` and `zmax` values to get the result you want:

[image: depthmap parameters]

- Rotate and move the mesh to get the position/orientation you want. And then save a snapshot of the scene adjusting the parameters as you want:

[image: saving snapshot]

#### Final result:

[image: final depthmap]

Comment: This works manually, but do you know of anything you can batch process with? My understanding of meshlabserver is that it can only perform operations in the "Filters" menu of the application.

Comment: Um... In meshlab you can't save a snapshot programmatically. Let me find a way to do this programmatically using python.